# Find all values of $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = n/6$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, totient-function

Using the product formula (the formula with the prime factors of $n$), I got
$$1=6\frac{(P_1-1)}{P_1}\frac{(P_2-1)}{P_2}\cdots\frac{(P_k-1)}{P_k}\,.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Additionally, if you are looking for prsomebody to check your proof, please update your post to include the tag [tag:proof-verification].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think the proof is enough, as it stands. There is a small ingredient. We are taking the product, with one or more primes, of $\frac{p-1}{p}.$

There are two types of potential problems. Some cancellation is possible, putting the product in lowest terms may be a bit surprising. Second, we can get the product arbitrarily close to $\frac{1}{6}$ byt choosing many large primes.

However: the collection of chosen primes is finite, and one of them is largest, call that $q.$ For any of the other, smaller primes, since $p<q,$ we also have $p-1 < q.$ That means that the numerator of the product fraction is not divisible by $q.$ When we put the fraction in lowest terms, the denominator is still divisible by $q.$

For your problem, this means that the largest prime involved, $q,$ must be a factor of $6.$ The possibilities for the product are just:
$$ \{ \}, \frac{1}{1}   $$
$$ \{ 2\}, \frac{1}{2}   $$
$$ \{ 3\}, \frac{2}{3}   $$
$$ \{ 2,3\}, \frac{1}{3}   $$

Answer (score -1):

Hints:

We know that if $\;p_1,...,p_k\;$ are the different primes diving $\;n\;$ , then

$$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{j=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_j}\right)$$

Well, take it now...And I couldn't completely understand what you wrote, but I think you're on the right track: there is no solution.

Comment: i used the same definition but because i couldnt type the product symbol i used the definition of the product....anyway thanks for verifying that there is no solution